# Git hook to check if QDebug is being used?

Tags: c++, git, qt, qt5, githooks

I know how to put in place a git hook but I would like to use one to prevent a commit which includes `QDebug`. How should I check for `#include <QDebug>` in a i.e `file.h` source file?

Comment: I assume you would have to search any staged files for that text. I would read the example template https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/templates/hooks--pre-commit.sample